# Adding extra documents in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I would like to add extra documents (like reference letters and certificates) to the moderncv in a way that everything is in the same pdf. I can´t include them as text because they will actually be scanned copies.

Is there any way to add it so every scan occupies an extra page in the same pdf or has the template been created to just have the CV and cover letter?

Comment: There exists also a package called `attachfile` (https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/attachfile) which allows to make a link out of for example a word ("Attached: Cover Leter") and which opens an attached file. You generate the PDF but it includes attached files.

Answer (score 4):

The [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) document class can handle this just like any other document class. Easiest would be to include

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
```

in your preamble and insert

```
\includepdf{<file>}
```

wherever you want to include a PDF `<file>`. `<file>` can be multi-page (or not) and you can specify the pages to include. See the [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) for options or choices.

Comment: Using pdfpages somehow makes my page numbering disappear, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @user138784: Yes, that's the default, as [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) inserts the pages as-is. You can use the `pagecommand={..}` key-value to add commands to be executed with every page that is included via `\includepdf`. Some people use `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}` to add a `plain` page style (and therefore page numbers at the bottom).

Comment: No, I mean, all page numbers, not only those on the included pages but also those on the main document.

Comment: @user138784: Typically a CV (or very short resume) is supplied without page numbers by default. That is, the page style is most likely set to `empty`. Try adding `\pagestyle{plain}` to your preamble, or load the [`fancyhdr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and insert them in the usual way...

Comment: I have the same symptoms and when not using includepdf *at the end* I get pagenumbers while I do not get them when I use includepdf. Strangely using includepdf at the beginning (before \maketitle) keeps the page numbers.